# Linearizing hyperbolic magnetic Hall sensor response

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, sensor

I am working on a project where I need high precision measurement of distance using a magnet and Hall sensor. The response is similar as in the graph below, meaning that the voltage changes much more when the magnet is close to the sensor than further away. I would like to use linearize the response preferably using analog circuit so that I can get the highest range possible out of the ADC. I have tried to simulate the circuit using antilog opamp amplifier and also tried various transistor circuits, but I really have no clue how to approach this  challenge.

[image]

Comment: What is the active distance range needed? || Do you have to use a Hall sensor?  A time of flight sensor may work well.  || [ST page](https://www.st.com/en/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/time-of-flight-sensors.html) || [Lots of links](https://www.google.com/search?q=st+tim+of+flight+sensor&oq=st+tim+of+flight+sensor&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13i512j69i64l2j69i65j69i61j69i60l2.7198j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - web search.

Comment: "High precision" -- how high? Will your precision account for component tolerances (sensors aren't terrifically precise, generally speaking)? Magnet tempco/drift?  What about geometry changes like tilt of the sensor/magnet, or nearby metal parts (or not-so-nearby large metal parts..!), or orientation of the whole machine versus Earth's magnetic field?

Comment: @TimWilliams Long ago we had an oscilloscope in a university lab labelled "Use facing North" . I suspect it may have been a joke, but the label stayed put.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple problem. Maximizing ADC range can be done, but, you can't really linearized an existing signal. Sometimes, changing the excitation of the sensor can make the difference, other times, it can't.

When you can, often it is by changing the side of the sensing element or changing the excitation source type (example constant voltage vs constant current). Other time the solution to place the sensing element in the feedback loop of an amplifier.

When you can't linearize, this implies you have a large dynamic range. Sadly, often, the only solution is to have multiple range just like a multimeter. There are many ways to do it. You can use an analog multiplexer, programmable gain amplifier, a dedicated analog IC, a programmable excitation source or many other technique to get this dynamic range.

But before going that route, ask yourself, what resolution is required at sampling. Maybe a better ADC would be sufficient to reach this level of accuracy without all the complexity.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I was wondering about solving this issue using analog circuit mostly out of curiosity, but really in my case a much better solution is to use external precise ADC like ADS1115 and it will be a much better solution.

Comment: I can't recall the part number, but I know that LT and TI have an ADC with integrated programmable gain amplifier. Maybe look into those. (ADS1257))

Answer (score 1):

Usually adding bits to the ADC is easier and more stable than trying to do something nonlinear ahead of the ADC. Even a cheap 16-bit ADC will be more stable ratiometrically than very expensive resistor dividers, let alone a nonlinear network, for example. Once you have digitized the input, of course you can apply whatever transformations you like to the value (but, of course, the resolution will still be grainy and the signal more noisy when the object is distant).

Sometimes there are feedback techniques that can work to tame this kind of behavior, but if you are using a commercial Hall sensor that may not be possible.

Another approach is to use something like a multiplier chip to generate a square-root function  so that (as an example) 1 stays 1 and 0.01 becomes 0.1, however such chips are rather expensive compared to a better ADC and, even though laser-trimmed and containing precision circuits, they are not that accurate or stable. They are, however, likely better than what can build easily so perhaps worth looking at.